# How do I watch xfinity in ubuntu?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I am trying to play xfinity's content on my ubuntu 17.10 installation, but when I open my xfinity page in chrome 63 or firefox 57, I get [this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7utd8.png).

I tried installing the wine/playonlinux combo described [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2348795&p=13596670#post13596670), but after the installation was complete, I would get a dialog box saying that wine crashed when I opened firefox.

Comment: Have you tried using an extension to set the User-Agent to chrome or firefox on Windows 10?

Comment: Try this question, see if it's any help: [Xfinity tv not using pipelight flash](https://askubuntu.com/q/539564/301745). I think Firefox stopped supporting NPAPI plugins, so you might need to use Firefox Extended Support Release (ESR).

Comment: Flash still works in Firefox though.